# Single page responsive dropdown menu - hide dropdown on "a" click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

Building a single page layout with a responsive dropdown menu. Issue I'm having is trying to figure out if I can add a call in the .js file to collapse the opened menu once a user clicks on the 'a' jump link.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).find(".button-mobile").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });
      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
          }
        });
      };
      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
      resizeFix = function() {
        var mediasize = 960;
        if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }
        if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      format: "multitoggle"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #head-mobile {
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #head-mobile {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:last-child {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a,
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

li.buttonfill {
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

li.buttonfill:hover {
  background-color: rgba(226, 226, 226, .2);
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(251, 252, 252, 0.5);
    background-color: #A31610;
  }
  #cssmenu>ul>li:last-child {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(251, 252, 252, 0.5);
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li:hover {
    background: #C22D32;
  }
  #cssmenu>ul>li {
    padding: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu #head-mobile {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .button-mobile {
    width: 55px;
    height: 46px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: -65px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 12399994;
  }
  .button-mobile:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 28px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
    content: '';
  }
  .button-mobile:before {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 28px;
    background: #FFF;
    content: '';
  }
  .button-mobile.menu-opened:after {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 27px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .button-mobile.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 27px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .container.logo-nav,
  .container.logo-nav>.sixteen.columns {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="container logo-nav">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <nav id="cssmenu">
        <div id="head-mobile"></div>
        <div class="button-mobile"></div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#research-media" class="smoothScroll">RESEARCH-MEDIA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#creative" class="smoothScroll">CREATIVE</a></li>
          <li class="buttonfill"><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</header>
<!--  End Header -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your .menumaker() call add a listener on the "a" tags and fire a function to close all menus.

```
$("#cssmenu ul li a").click(function(){
    //fire another click to the menu button to toggle it closed.
});
```

Comment: Was able to get it to work with `  $("#cssmenu ul:has(li) a").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#cssmenu ul").hide();
    $(this).next("ul").show();
    $(this).next(".button-mobile").removeClass('menu-opened');
  });` but having an issue where I can't remove the hamburger opened class using that last line of js.

Comment: Got it... my js sucks as my order was out of whack... this worked `(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      format: "multitoggle"
    });
  });
  $("#cssmenu ul:has(li) a").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#cssmenu ul").hide();
    $(".button-mobile").removeClass('menu-opened');
    $(this).next("ul").show();

  });` Thank you for helping me out.